# Why is it possible to submit an answer to a closed question by tweaking the HTML of the page?

Tags: bug, answers, closed-questions

One time, I was writing an answer to a question, when the question was closed. I had spent a little time on the question, so I didn't want to lose it. The `post` button was disabled, so I inspected it and saw that there was a single attribute disabling it:

```
disabled = "disabled"
```

I undid it, and was able to post my answer, even though the question was closed. There was no JS to keep me from posting it. Is this intentional, or just a mistake that the developers never thought about?